# Spring Boot Eureka - Faster offline detection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am using Spring Boot with Eureka and it works really good. But since a few hours, I wanted to detect offline Eureka instances/clients more quickly and I found no good documentation about Eureka's configuration properties. And I'm not even sure if it's possible because Eureka seems to presume that clients send their updates every 30 seconds.

I started to deactivate self-preservation mode and to increase the speed of renewal and interval updates and lower expiration durations but my Eureka server still needs two minutes to discover its offline clients.

After changing the renewal percent threshold the Eureka server didn't remove offline clients ever.

Is there any way to detect offline Eureka clients more quickly?

Server configuration:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false
    eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 10000
    response-cache-update-interval-ms: 5000
```

Client configuration:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
  instance:
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 15
```

edit:
Even health check url is not called more often. It is still called every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct option to change the schedule was:

```
eureka.client.instance-info-replication-interval-seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Ribbon configuration. Ribbon can cache servers configuration upfront during startup and make use of it when Eureka-sever is down. Please check if ribbon is enabled on eureka-client app